# "OperationalError at /checkout table home_checkout has no column named name" in my Django project

Tags: python-3.x, django, sqlite, django-models, django-views

Hello to who ever sees this,

Hope you all are doing great,

I was working on my first Django project and I am facing this error for a while now.
I added another form in same format without any hussle but idk why this is happening with this particular form.

Hope I could get some help. Thanks in advance.

python version - 3.11.3

Django version - 4.2

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Checkout(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=122)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=122)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=122)
    address = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,HttpResponse
from datetime import datetime
from home.models import Checkout

def checkout(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        phone = request.POST.get('phone')
        address = request.POST.get('address')
        date = datetime.today()
        checkout = Checkout(name=name , email = email, phone = phone, address= address, date=date)
        checkout.save()
    return render(request, 'checkout.html')
```

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Checkout</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="checkout" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone number">
        <textarea name="address" id="address" placeholder="Please enter your address"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Checkout">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Expected result : Saving in db

Comment: sounds like you havent run `makemigrations` and `migrate` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/migrations/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've already tried to run those but no luck :(

Comment: So have you created & applied the migration? How does it look like? How does the DB table for `Checkout` model look like?